# Creating revolving video wall in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Any thoughts on how to create a revolving videos wall similar to [Microsoft's "I'm a PC"](http://imapc.lifewithoutwalls.com/) in flash? The one on Microsoft site is done in Silverlight. I'm a newbie to flash and AS3, so any guidance and advices are greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Jacques

Answer (score 1):

You might [start here](http://www.lemlinh.com/flash-source-3d-curve-wall/) as the source code is included. See the [demo](http://www.lemlinh.com/demoflash/gallery/3d_curve_wall_1715/flashmo_098_3d_curve_wall.swf).

You can also use [Papervision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) and look at the examples provided to build your own wall.

And you might also consider using only javascript and images (or a canvas), like Google Maps. Someone gave it a try, [have a look at this](http://www.yango.co.uk/blog/?p=3).

**// Also:**

Once you're done with the thumbnails stitched together, just open a video player in a new (scene | layer) when you register a click on one of the image. There are a few video players out there for FLV videos. There is an included [FLVPlayback component](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html) in Adobe Flash that you can [customize](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/custom_flvcomp.html), but there are also a few open sources one: [Flash-Ajava Video Component](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flash-Ajax_Video_Component), [FLV Player](http://flv-player.net/) or [OS FLV](http://www.osflv.com/).